# openXML tables not being read in MS word

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to read all the tables from a word file into a list, although for some reason the count is 0 regardless of how many tables are in the file. Here's my code.

```
public void FindAndReplace(string DocPath)
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocPath, true))
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
      //Text titlePlaceholder = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>().Where((x) => x.Text == "Compliance Review By:").First();
      List<Table> tables = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Table>().ToList();
      System.Console.WriteLine(tables.Count);
```

tables.Count = 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it certain that the document contains "real" Word tables? How did you go about inserting a table and WHERE did you insert it: in the main document body, a header, a footer, a text box...?

Comment: I went to the insert tab and chose insert table. I inserted it into the main body, not a text box, header or footer. I can't imagine there's any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is *READ* the tables, then there's no need to open the document for editing (which is what you're doing currently)

Set the second parameter to false in WordprocessingDocument.Open() to open for reading. This will prevent the error related to opening an entry more than once in Update mode (I assume that's what you're running into anyway).

## Solution based on chatter

The real culprit here has to do with using the wrong OpenXml namespace when examining tables in the document. When looking for Descendants of type Table, the passed-in type must be OpenXml.*Wordprocessing*.Table, **NOT** OpenXml.*Drawing*.Table

I don't know what type of object the OpenXml.Drawing.Table is used for. I'll ask about this in a separate question.

Comment: I'm trying to edit as well, but I need to be able to read before I can edit. Either way, switching the second parameter didn't change anything anyway.

Comment: And you're definitely not getting any exceptions? Can you put the word document in dropbox or google drive and paste the link here? I have very similar logic to yours in one of my own projects, so I know you're close.

Comment: No exceptions whatsoever. Unfortunately the document contains sensitive data that my employer doesn't want me to just hand out. However I did try using a dummy file that I created and added a single table to it. I still end up with tables.Count == 0.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your own code and it worked fine with the one change I suggested (using a dummy document with a single table). Can you upload your dummy document to dropbox and paste the link?

Comment: It might have something to do with the context I'm using it in. That's a method inside of an external class (which is also part of an interface), and in my main I'm creating an instance of that class as the interface, and calling FindAndReplace. I'm 100% sure there is nothing wrong with the word document.

    MyInterface classname = new MyClass();

    MyClass.FindAndReplace(docpath);

Comment: When you say "external class", what do you mean? A class in a library outside of your main program? A class in a separate file in the same project? When you say the class is part of an interface, do you mean the class implements an interface? I'm clarifying so I can try to re-create the problem.

Comment: The class is in a separate file in the same project and it implements an interface (my apologies, I'm new to this interface thing). I'm declaring it like so...

IModule name = new Name(FullName.Text);

Name is the class, IModule is the interface, and FullName is a windows forms text box.

Comment: No worries, the language takes a bit to adapt to. I’ll give it a shot when I’m back at my desk. Also, I wasn’t suggesting there’s a problem with the word doc, just that there might be a difference with mine based on version. If I had your doc, I could exclude that as a cause.

Comment: As much as I'd love to provide it for you, onedrive, google drive, and dropbox are all blocked in my office. I could email the file to you if that works?

Comment: I'm using office 2016 if that helps

Comment: I'm hesitant to give out my e-mail address because I've SO users frown on this. I did find a 2016 doc template online that has tables, so I tried that with the code as you described: A `main()` function instantiating an object of type `Name` that implements `IModule` interface with `FindAndReplace()` method. That method executes the code you pasted and writes "4" to the console because there are 4 tables in the doc template.

Comment: I put my code on Google drive [(link to project)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HrUm1KNo96LAWzYxPtS_c8khv_mcpjr9/view?usp=sharing). Take a look when you get home.

Comment: Ok thank you. The only thing I can think of is that it isn't opening the file properly. I have it execute the main function when a user clicks a winforms button. Anyway I'll take a look at home. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing anything differently. I've provided a link of my own (proprietary info excluded) to see if anything stands out, but as far as I can tell we've both followed the same procedure.

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=AD1CAC67301A8000%21823&cid=AD1CAC67301A8000

Comment: I'm getting a message that the item might not exist or is no longer available.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference that your project is winforms, but I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: If you change `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing` to `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` in title.cs, your logic will work. No tables of type Drawing.Table are in the document, but there are tables of type Wordprocessing.Table. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just used the recommended using statements. I didn't know there was a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are referencing a wrong `Table`. This should work:

```
var tables = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Anu start had the answer in the comments. The problem was that I was using an incorrect namespace. Instead of using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table I was using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Table